# Spring Security Basic Auth Prompt Appearing

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Why would I get the basic auth prompt when I go to /preregistered/* ?  I thought the below configuration would only make basic auth apply when /services/** url path was matched. I'm using spring-security 3.1.0.M1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dc" />
    <global-method-security />
    <http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/public/**" />
    <http pattern="/services/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>
    <http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
            access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/preregistered/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/preregistered/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/registered/*"
            access="ROLE_USER"
            requires-channel="http"/>
          <intercept-url
            pattern="/secured/*"
            access="ROLE_USER"
            requires-channel="https"/>
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
            login-page="/auth/login.html"
            default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html" />
         <logout invalidate-session="true" 
              logout-url="/auth/logout.html" 
              success-handler-ref="DCLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="xmlAuthenticationFilter" />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="am">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="xmlAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to reach an .xhtml under `/preregistered` ?

If you try to reach `http://yoururl.com/preregistered/something.xhtml`.

Your `intercept-url` definition:

```
<intercept-url
        pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
        access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
```

will intercept it.

Comment: Simeon is correct - remember `intercept-url` declarations are evaluated top to bottom, and the first one matching is the winner.